# How to add more details on tensorboard using estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I made my model following by https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn.

I added SummarySaverHook to my model

```
    summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    100,
    output_dir='C:/Users/dir',
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

# Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, training_hooks=[summary_hook])
```

But when i run a get only enqueue_input chart(I don't known what is it) and model graph. I want get accuracy and loss charts.

So i want a couple of details in my tensorboard.

1. Loss and accuraty chars
2. It possible to get accuracy chart in time, because in estimator I only get accuracy after final step.
3. Can i get more details in tensorboard, like wrong predicted images? But without Session and Graph creation, only from estimator api?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use summary_hook. You just need to specify desired metrics with `tf.metrics` right after you specify logits.

```
 logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

 predictions = {
          "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
          "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
 }

 accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['classes']
 tf.summary.scalar('acc', accuracy[1])
```

And put this 
`tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)` 
right after your inputs, if you haven't done so.

You can plot evaluation metrics by inserting `eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': accuracy}` dict to `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec`

You can use `tf.summary` for visualizing images, weights and biases, etc.